# How can I select a html element which loaded dynamically in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, hook, getelementbyid

I want to select a specific html element that created dynamically. But "list" variable which create the html blocks is filling with http request and dom not loaded immediately. I want to select the element via id that got from url and equal to list item's id. So selected element is undefined even if I select the element in ngAfterViewInit hook. How can I select?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
        <div [id]="item.id">{{item.content}}</div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
list = null;
selectedItemId = null;

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedItemId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
}

getList() {
    this.http.get('http://api.example.com').subscribe(
        result => this.list = result
    )
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const htmlElement= document.getElementById(this.selectedItemId);

    /* Some codes that using htmlElement variable */
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Comment: have you tried adding and `*ngIf="list"` on the wrapper block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you refer to the HTML elements with `@ViewChildren`, you can subscribe to the `QueryList.changes` event to be notified when the elements appear in the DOM.

In the template, set a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) on the item elements:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
    <div #itemElement [id]="item.id">{{item.content}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

In the code, use that variable name to refer to the elements with `ViewChildren`:

```js
@ViewChildren("itemElement") private itemElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.itemElements.changes.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Item elements are now in the DOM!", this.itemElements.length);
    const htmlElement = document.getElementById(this.selectedItemId);
    ...
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-offhhv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo. Please note that the `ng-container` is not necessary if it contains only one `div` element. You can apply the `*ngFor` directive directly to that element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setTimeout` (After http request finishes, your code is executed, then you left zone and Angular run check and add elements, after timeout is executed):

```
this.http.get('http://api.example.com').subscribe(
    result => this.list = result;
    setTimeout(() => console.log(document.getElementById(this.selectedItemId)))
)
```